# How to convert a PostGIS geometry stored as text back into a geometry?

Tags: postgis

I have a geometry column stored as text e.g.:

```
'010100002091080000000000804D624041000000C066735741'
```

in PostgreSQL db with PostGIS. This for a point geometry with the EPSG:2193.

How do I convert this text column to a geometry column?

I have seen [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140409/convert-string-column-back-to-geometry-column?rq=1) question which is essentially the same, but the answer does not work.

Comment: Is that an actual example or random numbers?

Comment: '023013040523432420' is not a wkb ...

Comment: My apologies, those are random numbers. I'll edit it with a proper MWE.

Comment: OK, rather embarrassingly I've realised that there are null geometries. Hence the parsing error. I'm not sure if I should take down the question or leave it up to serve as a warning to newbies and, someone who should have done better such as myself...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply:

```
ALTER TABLE opr_records ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE Geometry USING geom::Geometry;
```

Or this if you're using a specific geometry (the post you linked to was using point) and SRID (4326 here):

```
ALTER TABLE opr_records ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE Geometry(POINT, 4326) USING ST_SetSRID(geom::Geometry,4326);
```

Comment: When running the above I get the following error:

ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry

Comment: That'll happen if you've got some rows with values in `geom` that can't be cast into geometries. I tried the example you've just added to your question, and it works. SRID 2193.
You should try identifying which rows are giving you problems and handle them some other way.

Comment: After I realised this I saw this comment. Terrible! I think it is good to leave this question up as the other is not properly flagged as the right answer.

Comment: The solution to removing the geometries was to `UPDATE table SET the_geom = NULL WHERE the_geom = '';`.